# Create a SQL Server view with different permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

I have created a view in Database A that looks at tables in Database B that the users in Database A do not have access to (HR Data).

Is there a way I can grant anybody calling the view in Database A permissions to see the results, without giving access to the underlying tables?

Both databases are on the same instance, SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

You can just

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::[schema].[theView] TO User1,User2
```

in your Database A? This way you'd just give SELECT permissions to the view itself, and not the tables.

If you have a lot of cases like this, you can also consider creating a special schema for this and do:

```sql
GRANT select ON Schema :: [DBO] TO User1
```

instead.